# c++ picking function is not working

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, directx

i have this picking function but it doesn't seems to work. the function should return true if it collide with an object but it return 0; and it never change.
here is my picking function

```
BOOL D3dDevice::Picking(HWND hWnd, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev, CXFileEntity *entity)
{
 D3DXVECTOR3 v;
 D3DXMATRIX matProj;
 POINT pt;
 D3DVIEWPORT9 vp;
 GetCursorPos(&pt);
 ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
 d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj);
 d3ddev->GetViewport(&vp);
 v.x =  ( ( ( 2.0f * pt.x ) / vp.Height  ) - 1 ) / matProj._11;
 v.y = -( ( ( 2.0f * pt.x ) / vp.Width ) - 1 ) / matProj._22;
 v.z =  1.0f;

 D3DXMATRIX m;
 D3DXVECTOR3 rayOrigin,rayDir;
 D3DXMATRIX matView;
 d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);

 D3DXMatrixInverse( &m, NULL, &matView );

 // Transform the screen space pick ray into 3D space
 rayDir.x  = v.x*m._11 + v.y*m._21 + v.z*m._31;
 rayDir.y  = v.x*m._12 + v.y*m._22 + v.z*m._32;
 rayDir.z  = v.x*m._13 + v.y*m._23 + v.z*m._33;
 rayOrigin.x = m._41;
 rayOrigin.y = m._42;
 rayOrigin.z = m._43;

 // Use inverse of matrix
 D3DXMATRIX matInverse, matWorld;
 d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);

 // Use inverse of matrix
 D3DXMatrixInverse(&matInverse,NULL,&matWorld);

 // Transform ray origin and direction by inv matrix
 D3DXVECTOR3 rayObjOrigin,rayObjDirection, rayDirection;

 D3DXVec3TransformCoord(&rayObjOrigin,&rayOrigin,&matInverse);
 D3DXVec3TransformNormal(&rayObjDirection,&rayDirection,&matInverse);
 D3DXVec3Normalize(&rayObjDirection,&rayObjDirection);

 BOOL hasHit;
 float distanceToCollision;

 D3DXIntersect(entity->pDrawMesh, &rayObjOrigin, &rayObjDirection, &hasHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distanceToCollision, NULL, NULL);

 return hasHit;
}
```

note: my pDrawMesh is mutable LPD3DXMESH not LPD3DXBASEMESH would that make a different?
**UPDATE**

```
BOOL D3dDevice::Picking(HWND hWnd, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev, CXFileEntity *entity)
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 v;
    D3DXMATRIX matProj;
    POINT pt;
    D3DVIEWPORT9 vp;
    D3DXMATRIX matInverse, matWorld;
    D3DXMATRIX m;
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayOrigin,rayDir;
    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayObjSpace;
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayObjOrigin,rayObjDirection, rayDirection;

    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj);
    d3ddev->GetViewport(&vp);

    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);

    // Use inverse of matrix
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);
    D3DXVECTOR3 vec3( pt.x, pt.y, 1.0f );
    D3DXVec3Unproject( &rayObjSpace, &vec3, &vp, &matProj, &matView, &matWorld );
    // Transform ray origin and direction by inv matrix

    D3DXMATRIX invWorld;
    D3DXMatrixInverse( &invWorld, NULL, &matWorld );

    D3DXVECTOR3 camObjSpace;
    D3DXVECTOR3 camPos(0.0, 0.0, -14.0f);
    D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &camObjSpace, &camPos, &invWorld ); 

    rayDir = rayObjSpace - camObjSpace;

    BOOL hasHit;
    float distanceToCollision;

    if(FAILED(D3DXIntersect(entity->pDrawMesh, &rayObjSpace, &rayDir, &hasHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distanceToCollision, NULL, NULL)))
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    };

    if(hasHit==1)
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    }

    return hasHit;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Now it doesn't intersect ;/.
    BOOL D3dDevice::Picking(HWND hWnd, LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev, CXFileEntity *entity, int z)
    {
        D3DXVECTOR3 v;
        POINT pt;
        D3DVIEWPORT9 vp;
        D3DXMATRIX matInverse, matWorld, m, matView, matProj;

```
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj);
    d3ddev->GetViewport(&vp);
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);
    d3ddev->GetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);

    // Use inverse of matrix
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayPos(pt.x, pt.y,0); // near-plane position
    D3DXVECTOR3 rayDir(pt.x, pt.x,1); // far-plane position
    D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayPos,&rayPos,&vp,&matProj,&matView,&matWorld);
    D3DXVec3Unproject(&rayDir,&rayDir,&vp,&matProj,&matView,&matWorld);
    rayDir -= rayPos; // make a direction from the 2 positions
    D3DXVec3Normalize(&rayDir,&rayDir); // don't know if this is necessary.
    // Transform ray origin and direction by inv matrix

    BOOL hasHit;
    float distanceToCollision;

    if(FAILED(D3DXIntersect(entity->pDrawMesh, &rayPos, &rayDir, &hasHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distanceToCollision, NULL, NULL)))
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    };

    if(hasHit!=0)
        PostQuitMessage(0);

    return hasHit;
}
```

UPDATE 3:
Ok now it always intersect ;/ after changing values in this function

```
D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                               D3DXToRadian(45),    // the horizontal field of view
                               (FLOAT)Width / (FLOAT)Height, // aspect ratio
                               0.0f,   // the near view-plane
                               1.0f);    // the far view-plane
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code at all?

Comment: Holy crap that's a lot of capitalization.

Comment: The code is from here. http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/picking.html

Comment: yea i got it from there, and i did debug it but doesn't seem to work, no errors too

Comment: Maybe you should try debugging it and make a hypothesis about what might be wrong. It will be unlikely to get an answer by "hey, this doesn't work, what is wrong?", without putting some effort in it yourself...

Comment: If you debugged the code, then you should at least know exactly where and how things start going wrong. Posting that information would be a good start.

Comment: ok i did debug my code all i got is that `D3DXIntersect` returns 0 it should return true or false

Comment: 0 is FALSE, so your objects don't intersect. My guess would be that your coordinates or transformations are wrong so the two never intersect.

Comment: it can't be wrong because im getting all my information from my device

Comment: Sounds like you're using `cout` or something similar to "debug", is that correct? If so, you should look into using a proper debugger that lets you set breakpoints, step through the code and examine variables. That way you can easily see if the correct values are being passed to `D3DXIntersect`.

Comment: for sure im not using cout to debug im using break points

Comment: that is the other problem all varabiles  have just bunch of numbers i don't know what these numbers stand for

Comment: Well, that's your main problem then. You're not doing programming, you're doing magic. All the debugging tools in the world can't help you if you can't tell correct and incorrect behavior/states apart. Figure out what you're doing, and chances are you'll spot the error yourself.

Comment: it might be because my mesh is in mutable LPD3DXMESH not in LPD3DXBASEMESH. im using my mesh in D3DXIntersect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ray picking is a fun one.  You basically need to start off by converting a screen coordinate into projection space.  As DirectX projection space (for x,y) ranges from -1 to 1 in x and y then you need to do the following.

```
float px = (((float)mousex / SCREEN_WIDTH) * 2.0f) - 1.0f;
float py = -(((float)mousey / SCREEN_HEIGHT) * 2.0f) - 1.0f;
```

Not py has the minus in front because screen coord go from top to bottom where projection space is the opposite.

You now have your position in projection space.  So you need to create a vector along that point.  Thankfully thats nice and easy too.

```
float pz = 1.0f;
```

Now we can unproject this back into object space:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 rayObjSpace;
D3DXVec3Unproject( &rayObjSpace, &rayOut, &viewport, &projectionMatrix, &viewMatrix, &worldMatrix );
```

Finally plug that into D3DXIntersect and you are ready to go :)

**Edit**:  I do realise there is a bug in my explanation above.  In fact with D3DXVec3Unproject you can pass in the actual screen coordinate x,y with a z of 1.

So:

```
D3DXVECTOR3 vec3( mousex, mousey, 1.0f );
D3DXVECTOR3 rayObjSpace;
D3DXVec3Unproject( &rayObjSpace, &vec3, &viewport, &projectionMatrix, &viewMatrix, &worldMatrix );
```

Much simpler.  As it is the view port transform is applied twice.

That said have you actually looked at the ray vectors you have been getting returned?  Do they even point towards the object?

**Edit 2:** Alright I'll be more specific.  Now you have the world position of the point you clicked on you can calculate the ray direction by doing the following.

```
 D3DXMATRIX invWorld;
 D3DXMatrixInverse( &invWorld, NULL, &world );

 D3DXVECTOR3 camObjSpace;
 D3DXVec3TransformCoord( &camObjSpace, &camPos, &invWorld ); 

 D3XVECTOR3 rayDir = rayObjSpace - camObjSpace;

 BOOL bHit = FALSE;
 float distToHit = true;
 HRESULT hr = D3DXIntersect( pMesh, &rayObjSpace, &rayDir, &bHit, NULL, NULL, NULL, &distToHit, NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: i tired it but it didn't work :'( i posted the code that i tired

Comment: i edit my code and posted it, here is the values what im getting for rayObjSpace {x=-21.815399 y=-14.083395 z=-86.000755 }

Comment: @Ramiz: Have you considered drawing the ray you produce?  I've found, in the past, its INCREDIBLY helpful for finding ray picking issues.  If you draw it and you can't see it then don't fear ... if it is pointing directly away from you you won't be able to see it.  move the camera slightly and does it appear where you expect?

Comment: i drawed my rays it followed my mouse. i noticed that my z for rays are like between 70-80 the value of it

Comment: is there anything that i can try?

Comment: @Goz i updated my code, the problem is now that the ray always collide with the object

Comment: @Ramilol: You are going from screen space to world space.  The front plane is at z= 0 and the far plane is at z = 1.  This is the whole point of projection space.  Furthermore a position can be stored in a vector but is NOT a vector, normalising it is a mistake.

Comment: @Ramilol: further if you wish to unproject 2 points as you do then set 1's Z to 0 and the other to 1.

Comment: @Goz ok when you told me about the 0 and the 1 i changed the values but not in just the unproject functions. i changed it in theD3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH function

Comment: @Ramilol:  *sigh* Don't change the projection matrix... What you are doing is hacking to try and get the results you are after.  The 0 to 1 Z-range is a projection SPACE thing.  That means once you have transformed everything by the projection matrix you are, now, in projection space.

Answer (score 0):

The logic that sets hasHit is in D3DXIntersect which we can't see. There are a load of other functions (which look like C functions) that we can't see either.

Comment: Its, quite obviously, a D3DX function.  Documentation is available in MSDN (or the DX SDK) and easy for anyone to look up.